# Struct ! Está dando erro na linha 47 no momento que compila, Segue o programa em c

Tags: c, struct

```
#define MAX 50
struct{
    int ra;
    char nome[MAX];
    float prova;
}aluno[5];

int main(){
    struct aluno;
    int i;
    int j;

    printf("Determine o Nome do Aluno %d: ", i+1);
    printf("Determine a Matricula do Aluno &d: ", i+1);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        fgets(aluno[i].nome,MAX,stdin);
        scanf("%i", &aluno[i].ra);
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        printf("Determine a nota da %d Prova: ", j+1);
        scanf("%f", &aluno[i].prova[j]);
      }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: O seu código tem 24 linhas. Como é que dá erro na 47?

Answer (score 3):

Quando você faz isso:

```
    struct aluno;
```

Você está tentando declarar uma variável incorretamente. Remova essa linha, pois `aluno` já foi declarado antes como um array de 5 posições com o tipo do `struct`.

Observe essa linha:

```
    printf("Determine a Matricula do Aluno &d: ", i+1);
```

Ao invés de `&d`, você deveria usar `%d`.

Esses dois primeiros `printf`s deveriam estar dentro do `for`, e não antes dele.

No seu segundo `for`, você usa três notas, mas não declarou as três no `struct`.

Acho que o que você queria era isso:

```
#define MAX 50
struct {
    int ra;
    char nome[MAX];
    float prova[3];
} aluno[5];

int main() {
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Determine o Nome do Aluno %d: ", i + 1);
        fgets(aluno[i].nome, MAX, stdin);

        printf("Determine a Matricula do Aluno &d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%i", &aluno[i].ra);

        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("Determine a nota da %d Prova: ", j + 1);
            scanf("%f", &aluno[i].prova[j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não entendi esse aluno[5] em baixo da struct, serve pra que?

Comment: @YODA Para dizer que aluno é um array de 5 posições e que cada posição tem um elemento com o tipo desse `struct` aí.

Comment: Não precisa de typedef? No caso a struct tem 3 variaveis e as outras duas vão ser preenchidas como?

Comment: @YODA Precisaria do `typedef` se fosse para declarar variáveis desse mesmo tipo `struct` em outros lugares, o que quase sempre é uma boa ideia. Mas nesse caso específico, isso ainda não é necessário.