# Não estou conseguindo realizar esses passos ! Queria ajuda

Tags: c, struct

(b) Encontre o aluno com maior nota da primeira prova.

(c) Encontre o aluno com maior média geral.

(d) Encontre o aluno com menor média geral.

```
#define MAX 50
struct {
    int ra;
    char nome[MAX];
    float prova[3];
} aluno[5];

int main() {
    int i;
    int j;
    float media, Mmedia, mmedia;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Determine o Nome do Aluno %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", &aluno[i].nome);

        printf("Determine a Matricula do Aluno %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%i", &aluno[i].ra);

        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("Determine a nota da %d Prova: ", j + 1);
            scanf("%f", &aluno[i].prova[j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pergunta anterior (não é duplicata): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/307649/132

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, embora não seja estritamente necessário, as coisas vão ficar mais fácil sse você adicionar um campo `float media` no seu `struct`. Para preencher esse campo, use uma variável `soma` dentro do for do `i` e dentro do laço do `j`, você vai somando as notas nessa vaariável. Depois do laço do `j`, você calcula a média e então preenche esse campo no `struct`.

Depois, você vai precisar de três variáveis `int` diferentes, para guardar o número dos alunos (de 0 a 4) que são a solução de cada um desses daí. Por exemplo, `int aluno_com_maior_nota_da_primeira_prova`, `int aluno_com_maior_media` e `int aluno_com_menor_media`. Inicialize todos com 0.

No final do laço do `i`, você põe um `if` para verificar se a nota da primeira prova do aluno `i` é melhor que a nota da primeira prova do aluno na posição `aluno_com_maior_nota_da_primeira_prova`. Você faz algo parecido com as outras duas variáveis.

Finalmente, depois do laço do `i`, você põe alguns `printf`s para mostrar quem são os alunos que atendem esse três critérios.

Além disso, as variáveis `media`, `Mmedia`, `mmedia` podem ser descartadas. O problema com elas é que você não quer saber qual é a média do aluno ou coisa semelhante e sim saber **qual aluno** que tem a média de acordo com o enunciado. Como os três problemas tratam de saber quais são os alunos e os alunos podem ser numerados de 0 a 4, então você estará lidando com três variáveis `int` e não `float`.