# Após digitar o Valor de P, não está rodando o printf do segundo for

Tags: c, struct, printf

```
#define MAX 15
#define TAM 2
struct
{
    char m[MAX];
    int ano;
    float v;
} car[TAM];

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int p;

    for(i=0; i<TAM; i++)
    {
        printf("Determine a Marca e Modelo do Carro %d: ", i+1);
        gets(car[i].m);
        printf("Determine o Ano do Carro %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &car[i].ano);
        printf("Determine o Valor do Carro1 %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &car[i].v);
        fflush(stdin);
    }

    printf("Determine o seu Orcamento: ");
    scanf("%f", &p);

    for(i<0; i<TAM; i++)
    {
        if(car[i].v<p)
        {
            printf("Marca: %s\nAno: %d\nPreco: %.2f", car[i].m, car[i].ano, car[i].v);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: no segundo `for` o inicio tá errado e devia ser `i = 0` e não `i < 0`. Isso é um erro de digitação mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Olhe isso:

```
int p;
// ...
scanf("%f", &p);
```

Acho que o que você queria era isso:

```
float p;
// ...
scanf("%f", &p);
```

Ou seja, era para usar `float` ao invés de `int`.

Além disso, nunca use `gets`. Na [sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/307649/132), você já utilizava o `fgets`, use aqui também.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, eu também encontrei somente estes erros:

> O segundo for deveria ser assim:

```
for(i = 0; i<TAM; i++) /*igual em vez de menor*/
```

> Você usou P como float mas declarou como int

```
int p;
```

Os colegas já haviam mencionado isso, aqui esta rodando corretamente.

Abraços